# Refreshing custom infowindow google maps

Tags: android, maps, infowindow

I have a custom info window with a favorites button, When clicked I would want the button to display a different favorites image indicating to the user that the waypoint is now on the users favorites. I dont know how to refresh the info window, everywhere I look on the internet they say to use marker.showInfoWindow(); however this does not work when running the app on my phone and plus documentation for google maps says:

> Note about refreshing an info window: The onInfoWindowClose() event
>   fires if the user refreshes an info window by tapping a marker that
>   already has an open info window. But if you programmatically call
>   Marker.showInfoWindow() on an open info window, the
>   onInfoWindowClose() event does not fire. The latter behavior is based
>   on the assumption that you are aware that the info window will close
>   and re-open.

I see other apps having content that updates in their apps so I know its possible I just don't know what sort of work around they are doing to get around this. Does anyone have a way to work around this? And im very new to all of this so please dumb down your answer. Thanks in advance for your efforts.

Comment: huh no one knows how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

When you tap on marker pass that marker object to your favorite web service method and when you get success from web-service response just write below lines of code:

```
if (marker != null && marker.isInfoWindowShown()) {
                                marker.hideInfoWindow();
                                marker.showInfoWindow();
                            }
```